# Preparing geojson files for use in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I need to prepare several GIS polygon datasets (in .tab or .shp) to geojson for use in PowerBI. I can easily convert to geojson using FME. However all my efforts have so far failed to work when our PowerBI uses have tried them in PowerBI. I have converted the coordinate system to EPSG:3857, which I understand Azure Maps and PowerBI requires. However the geojson files are still not loading into PowerBI/ Azure Maps.

Does PowerBI requites a certain data schema? Perhaps it requires certain fields and values.